# Написание конфигурационного файла для кроссплатформенного приложения

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

Работаю в MSVC, но приложение разрабатывается кроссплатформенное. Использую фреймворк boost, там есть файл config.hpp, в котором указывается множество параметров посредством препроцессора: константы компилятора, тип системы, всякие суффиксы и префиксы, еще куча макросов. В целом, меня устраивает то, в каком виде оформлена данная часть в boost.

Вопрос: написана ли эта часть разработчиками boost индивидуально, или же использовался какой-то общепринятый шаблон? Считается ли все написанное там хорошим примером? Сейчас я предполагаю взять эти config-хедеры, немного откорректировать, выкинуть ненужное, переименовать макросы и воткнуть в свое приложение. А далее писать код приложения с учетом такой конфигурации.

Вопрос-примечание: правильно ли я понимаю, что данный файл и все следующие из него включения - это единственный раздел в boost, подключаемый ко всем остальным разделам (остальные - это всякие библиотеки), или же есть еще какие-то "настроечные" элементы?

Comment: *"немного откорректировать, выкинуть ненужное, переименовать макросы"* -- не самая хорошая идея. Больше скажу: плохая идея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какого-то общего шаблона нет, однако сама техника используется не редко. То есть для средних или больших проектов создают один или несколько заголовочников с такими вот общими объявлениями.

Реализация в Бусте хорошая, рекомендую брать на вооружение.

По поводу, есть ли другие глобальные настройки, скорее всего нет. Если вы назвали что-то "конфигурацией", глупо делать то же самое с другим названием. Бустом народ далеко не глупый занимается. Другой вопрос, что система заголовочников в Бусте весьма запутанная, у него даже утилита была для вычленения библиотек в отдельную поставку.